# how to open a pop-up page in rails 3 and load data from database

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ruby-on-rails + psql

I have list of pages. On some page click I have to open page in pop-up.

How I'll load data in that pop-up for specific page.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of loading dynamic data into a page without having to refresh the page is using AJAX calls to your backend and then handle the displaying of the data with JQuery/Javascript.  In order to do this it looks a little something like this:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            /*populate popup with returned data*/
        },
        failure: function(){
            /*display error message*/
        }
    });
</script>
```

For a full look at what ajax can do for you look at the API located here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/